# Виртуальные устройства android закрывают приложение при наличии обработчика событий onTextChange

Tags: android, kotlin

Использую android studio 4.1.3
Виртуальные устройства: Nexus 5 API24 и 2.7QVGA API24
Язык kotlin

При наличии обработчика событий addTextChangedListener и попытке поменять текст в указанном текстовом поле, виртуальные устройства сразу же закрывают приложение. При этом сборка осуществляется без ошибок. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с аналогичной проблемой?

```
    var et: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)


    et.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
            Log.d("checker","After")

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
            Log.d("checker","Before")
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
            Log.d("checker","Change")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Метод TODO() вызывает Runtime Exception: Not implemented. Уберите эти методы, и у вас перестанет падать приложение. Этот метод используется как заглушка. Читайте logcat, чтобы знать из-за чего падает приложение